# Convert an RDD [String] to a JSON File without converting to DataFrames [Scala]

Tags: scala

I have a file of RDD of Strings in the format :

```
78656|twitterId:14|Hi|2010-05-19
```

I want to convert this RDD[String] to a JSON file in the format :

```
"78656","twitterId:14","Hi","2010-05-19"
```

I am currently using the code :

```
tweetTable.toJSON.saveAsTextFile("Gaga")
```

to convert it to a JSON File but the data is in the format :

```
"_1":"78656|twitterId:14|Hi|2010-05-19"
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `"78656","twitterId:14","Hi","2010-05-19"` is not valid JSON, probably you want something like `{"id": "78656","twitterId": "14", "test": "Hi", "date": "2010-05-19"}` ?

Comment: what language are you using here, `python`, `r` or `scala`?

Comment: @VitaliyKotlyarenko : Yes, Sorry for the typo. The way you mentioned it is exactly the way i want it.

Comment: @Symbolix : I am using Scala.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have in the question, you can do something like this:

```
value <- "78656|twitterId:14|Hi|2010-05-19"
valueList <- strsplit(value, split ="\\|")
library("jsonlite")
res <- toJSON(valueList)
```

Comment: Is this is Scala ?

Comment: @user2122466 , no, it's `r` as you included the `r` tag in your question. I've removed the extra tags now.